# Streaming music or sound from phone to phone in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I searched a lot to find a phone-to-phone sound streaming solution but so far I found only phone->PC->phone solution (AirIt, Gmote).

As I intend to create an app that does a phone-to-phone streaming, I wonder if it possible at all. As there is no such app yet, it raises the possibility that it is not possible (because of the lack of processing power of phones, for example).

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone?
2. Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone in the same wifi network?
3. Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone in another wifi network over the Internet? If yes, how can they find each other (considering the local addresses they both can possess - 192.168.0.100 for example)

I hope you can compass me in the right direction.

Comment: You mean like a phone call?

Comment: No, I don't want to use the phone network, I intend to use the IP network and stream music or human talking from phone to phone.

Answer (score 2):

*Sounds like a fun question.*

If you record raw audio data, you'll most likely record `16 bit` [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM) data with a samplerate of `44100 Hz`.

`44100 Hz * 2 byte` means `88200 byte` per second, `88.2 kilobyte`.
You will want to transmit one stream from each client, so its `176.4 kilobyte per second`.

> Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone?

Recording it will be no problem. It is just data, so it can be transferred just like e.g. pictures of cats.

> Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone in the same wifi network?

Even using uncompressed transmission, this rate should be achievable easily on a wireless local area network.

> Can an Android phone send a sound stream to another phone in another wifi network over the Internet? If yes, how can they find each other (considering the local addresses they both can possess - 192.168.0.100 for example)

This get's trickier, as you'll have to fight with [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Address_Translation) to get unique IP address if you want to directly connect to a known IP address. But it is possible, if the connection has been established. In Germany, I usually have transfer rates that are by far high enough to transmit this data. That is, when I'm not throttled to `5 kb/s`...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, so technically it can be done. Do you have any idea why there are no working sample all over the Internet? Nobody has done it? And why the "big" companies (like S---- and V----) use **phone->(lots of) server->phone** communication? Using only phone would require less resources, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Nestor: Possibly, but it's about user experience, not resource efficiency. Direct transfer requires a different way of contacting than when you got servers available, e.g. direct IP addresses, which is infeasible. You might want to have a look at Tox. The clients aren't ready yet, but if I remember correctly, it's supposed to allow for P2P voice transfer. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: I assume then that it's not worth to create a phone-to-phone solution (and that's the main reason that there isn't any), and I'll suggest my clients to start looking for servers. With this analogy, I assume, video streaming is also not (easily) feasible from phone-to-phone.

Comment: If worth is proportional to usability, then it's not worth it. I'm not saying it's worthless, it has it's uses, even though the market may be a bit saturated with more comfortable solutions...